# Why does scipy's leastsq fail to produce cov_x matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, astropy, astronomy

I've recently been using specutils' `fit_lines`, which relies on scipy's `leastsq`, to fit Gaussian profiles to spectral lines. However, sometimes errors on the fits aren't being returned, because the cov_x matrix is being returned as a None value by scipy's `leastsq`. The fits are successful, ie the value of ierr returned is 'equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4, [meaning] the solution was found.' as stated in the `leastsq` docs, so that isn't the cause of the issue.

**My question is therefore two-fold** - firstly I wonder if anyone could help to explain why this is occurring, and perhaps more importantly, whether there is anything I can do to sort it.

I've spent a fair while searching through all the documentations and reading source code to figure out my issue, and while I'm not very confident in my knowledge of the stats side of it, I think the issue is occurring because when `leastsq` is trying to minimise the function, it's reaching a flat spot at the bottom rather than finding a single minimum? In the description of cov_x in the `leastsq` docs, it states 'A value of None indicates a singular matrix, which means the curvature in parameters x is numerically flat.'.

I have tried changing the various parameters such as epsfcn, xtol, but this hasn't helped unless I change the values by a large amount, and as I'm not 100% sure I understand what this is doing, I'm not really comfortable with just using that as a solution.

I've spent hours searching through google but haven't been able to find an answer to my issue, so I'd really appreciate any help anyone can offer!

```
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
from specutils import Spectrum1D
from specutils.fitting import fit_lines

#The arrays are:
Waves = [4379.25263541926,4380.261111703601,4381.26982022493,4382.278761036721,4383.2879341924645,4384.297339745673,4385.306977749856,4386.316848258552,4387.326951325295,4388.337287003648,4389.34785534717,4390.358656409448,4391.369690244064,4392.380956904633,4393.3924564447625,4394.404188918088,4395.416154378243,4396.428352878889,4397.440784473684,4398.453449216315,4399.466347160462,4400.479478359837,4401.492842868152,4402.50644073913,4403.520272026519,4404.534336784062,4405.548635065535,4406.563166924702,4407.5779324153655,4408.592931591316,4409.608164506378,4410.623631214367,4411.6393317691345,4412.655266224519,4413.671434634397,4414.687837052633,4415.704473533126,4416.721344129766,4417.738448896479,4418.7557878871785,4419.773361155814,4420.79116875633,4421.809210742687,4422.827487168868,4423.845998088853,4424.86474355665,4425.883723626264,4426.90293835173,4427.922387787075,4428.942071986359,4429.961991003635,4430.982144892989,4432.002533708497,4433.02315750427,4434.04401633441,4435.065110253052,4436.086439314323,4437.1080035723835,4438.129803081385,4439.1518378955125,4440.174108068944,4441.1966136558885,4442.219354710549,4443.242331287159,4444.265543439951,4445.28899122317,4446.312674691088,4447.3365938979705,4448.360748898113,4449.385139745807,4450.409766495372,4451.434629201126,4452.459727917414,4453.485062698576,4454.510633598985,4455.536440673005,4456.562483975033,4457.58876355946,4458.615279480707,4459.642031793189,4460.669020551353,4461.6962458096405,4462.723707622523,4463.75140604447,4464.779341129965,4465.8075129335175,4466.835921509631,4467.864566912838,4468.89344919767,4469.922568418684,4470.951924630434,4471.981517887507,4473.0113482444785,4474.041415755961,4475.071720476557,4476.102262460901,4477.133041763624,4478.164058439384]

 Flux = [-1.609175,-0.47427708,-0.60574985,-0.9217671,-0.14470458,1.7211268,-0.2885138,-0.0131763145,2.017541,-0.1551357,-0.62813485,0.42844194,0.23762748,0.1571013,0.18695286,-0.34576598,-0.079983935,0.11033059,0.6188194,-1.9645425,-1.1938491,-0.0038357377,1.2829684,-0.05393645,1.1477329,0.24603112,0.491022,0.55074716,-0.704924,-1.8671623,-0.96216017,1.0169754,1.9615287,1.8186992,0.4183128,6.846475,16.397682,32.69029,35.413,22.62686,6.9653482,0.36010352,1.244956,2.468903,-0.48600048,0.33933347,-0.45105207,0.21166058,-0.32686746,-0.26580417,-1.0156804,-0.676653,0.106376775,0.77532375,-0.18942682,-0.37561917,-0.5789215,0.7508146,0.4098208,-0.5737959,2.2061667,1.0370786,-1.323368,-2.41041,0.058673777,0.19647884,-0.7343958,-0.5081159,0.42372695,-0.057333924,-1.5179241,-1.119834,0.44848588,1.3844675,-0.19506846,-1.1519253,-0.6201113,0.3387856,0.33886302,0.028457977,-0.91573006,-0.7338029,1.1618475,-0.9490578,0.58596385,-0.086719885,-1.1230637,-1.3438936,-0.76436615,1.4362102,-0.20128047,-0.50129366,-0.9696252,-1.0146995,0.2377935,-0.593785,-1.0109384,-0.95101863]


#Then I created a Spectrum1D object with these in order to use specutils, but it uses the astropy fitting routine (with LevMarLeastSq), which relies on scipy's leastsq anyways, so shouldn't make a difference which is used.

#Then astropy's fitting routine is used, with a compound model of 2 Gaussian components and a constant background. 
model_init = models.Const1D(amplitude=0.) + models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=32.69028854, mean=4416.72134413, stddev=1.) + models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=2.20616674, mean=4440.17410807, stddev=1.) 

Fitter = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
#astropy fitting routine:
fitted_model = Fitter(model_init, Waves, Flux)

#Then the covariance matrix is accessible by doing 
print(Fitter.fit_info['cov_x'])
#Which for me returns None.
```

The plot of the fit looks ok though, I know it isn't picking up the smaller line in this instance, but that's not something I can really take out, as the point of my fits is to determine whether it is present in a sample of several spectra.
[image]

Comment: It would be good if you provide data to check.

Comment: Hi Razmik, thank you for your advice, I hadn't previously because the arrays are pretty big, but I'll add it in, and a bit more info about the code I'm running if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen if `leastsq` is also returning a value for `fjac`, the approximated Jacobian? I forget for sure off the top of my head (but can confirm when I'm at my computer), but this is used to computed `cov_x`, and I believe this is only computed if `leastsq` is *not* given an exact analytic derivative (the `Dfun` argument) which for something as simple as a sum of Gaussians I think it might be.

Comment: Ok, I double-checked and it *is* using the estimated jacobian, but it is also indeed erroring out when trying to compute cov_x due to a singular matrix.  I wonder if you could also post a plot of your data?

Comment: Hi @Iguananaut, thank you for looking into it. Yes fjac is returned, and that is true with the singular matrix error, I had previously tried copying the arrays out and trying to work cov_x out manually following the steps in the leastsq code to check. Will add a plot to my post.

Comment: Ok so one discovery I've made in some of the fits to brighter lines which also weren't producing the cov_x matrix, is that in my main code I was putting bounds on the position of the lines, and I think they were too narrow, so the function couldn't 'explore' enough of the parameter space to calculate the covariance matrix. That doesn't really help for the example I posted above though!